# Why is there a white vertical line on this DensityPlot?

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to convert all of my old **Mathematica 7.0** codes to **Mathematica 13.2**, and I'm experiencing some unexpected issues.  The following simple code draws a grayscale graphics:

```
intensity[x_] = (Sin[Pi x/8]/(2 Pi x/10) Cos[Pi x/5 + Pi/3])^2;

graphic = DensityPlot[
   intensity[x],
   {x, -3, 3}, {y, -1, 1},
   ColorFunction -> GrayLevel,
   PlotPoints -> {1000, 3}
   ];

Show[graphic]
```

Preview of what this code is doing:

[image]

The issue is the pesky white vertical line in the middle.  How can I get rid of it?  Why is this simple code doing that, with **Mathematica 13.2**?  I never had this, with version 7.0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's alerting you to the fact that your intensity function is only defined in terms of limits at x=0.  If you add `Exclusions -> None` the white line will go away.